# Java - Regex for oracle NUMBER(10,8) field

Tags: java, regex, precision

I have an `Oracle` column of data type `NUMBER`(10,8). I need to validate the input data via `java regex` before the storing the data in tables. As per oracle's data type, valid values include:

- 10 digits
- 2 digits . 8 digits
- 3 digits . 7 digits
- 4 digits . 6 digits
- no digits . 8 digits (is saved in Oracle as 0.12345678 but the input value can be like .12345678)

and so on. Negative values of these cases are also valid.
I can write regex for one case at a time. i.e we can check for 1234567891 with one regex. Then with changes in the range, we can write respective regex for all the possible combinations of the scale.

My sample regex : `^-?\\d{0,2}(?>\\.\\d{1,8})?$` : checks for 2 digits . 8 digits case.

Now I want to know, is there any easier way of checking all such values in one regex? One can always use a '|' operator but then the total number of such OR regex would be equal to the scale part of the data type.

Is there any elegant possible solution? Any pointers, suggestions are welcome!

**UPDATE :**

After @Andreas pointed out the actual meaning of (10,8), the question does seem to be misguided. Removing the invalid cases from the above mentioned, the valid cases are :

- (0/1/2 digits).(0/1/2/../8 digits)
- 0/1/2 digits
- negative cases

Comment: Much easier without using regex. Just split on `.` and test each side's length.

Comment: Using regex try [`^(?=[\d.]{1,10}$)(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d{1,8})$`](https://regex101.com/r/V4Etty/1)

Comment: @ctwheels yes, nice trick for this; I would do this if it just can't be achieved by regex. It is an existing module and a very good one. But if absolutely needed, I will change it.

Comment: What are the "-?", "(?>" and ")?" for?

Comment: @AleksandrMukhalov `-?` is making `-` optional (match it zero or one time) and `(?>)` is an atomic group which doesn't allow backtracking. See more info [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#atomic) about atomic groups

Comment: @ctwheels A good one, but it doesn't match 12.34567891

Comment: @HitchHiker and it shouldn't that's 11 chars

Comment: @ctwheels ohh my bad, Then this seems to do the trick! I will play around a bit more to consider the decimal point too.
Thanks a lot; can u please post this as an answer? It would be useful for future references.

Comment: @ctwheels thanks. Didn't know about atomic groups. And I've missed that negative values are also valid - hence the confusion about the "-?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misunderstood the meaning of [`NUMBER(10,8)`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#CHDHDHGB):

> Specify a fixed-point number using the following form:
>
> `NUMBER(p,s)`
>
> where:
>
> - `p` is the **precision**, or the maximum number of significant decimal digits, where the most significant digit is the left-most nonzero digit, and the least significant digit is the right-most known digit. [...]
> - `s` is the **scale**, or the number of digits from the decimal point to the least significant digit. [...]

It means maximum 10 significant decimal digits, with 8 digits from the decimal point, i.e. `2.8` only. The **scale** is *not* floating. Sure, you can have fewer on each side of the decimal point, but no mote than 2 on the left and 8 on the right.

Oracle names this a *fixed-point* number, and it is very distinct from a *floating-point* number, which uses the same keyword but without limits, i.e. `NUMBER`.

As for Oracle Database [number literal format](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00220), the format is:
[image]

If you exclude scientific notation, that means a regex of:

`^[+-]?(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{0,8})?|\.\d{1,8})$`

Comment: Oh the goodness, I'm so embarrassed right now! It was such a bad confusion about precision and scale... you are absolutely right! Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @HitchHiker You can change the accepted answer to be this answer, if you feel it better answers your question. The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49160551/5221149) does answer your question details more accurately, but not what I perceive to be your *real* question, i.e. how to validate a `NUMBER(10,8)` literal (excluding scientific notation).

Comment: Yes, I was updating my question :)

Answer (score 3):

#### EDIT

**Please note that this answer was provided prior to the OP's update and is no longer correct**. I will leave this here in case it helps any future readers, but at the time of writing this edit [Andreas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49160781/3600709) seems to be correct.

---

This may be easier to achieve by simply splitting the string on `.` and then testing each side's length, but this can still be achieved using regex alone.

[See this regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/V4Etty/1)

```
^(?=[\d.]{1,10}$)(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d{1,8})$
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?=[\d.]{1,10}$)` Positive lookahead to ensure the line has a maximum of 10 characters and is composed of only digits and `.`.
- `(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d{1,8})` Match either of the following options

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match any digit one or more times, optionally followed by a decimal point `.` and more digits (one or more). You can change `\.\d+` to `\.\d*` to match numbers like `1.` that don't have decimal numbers specified.
  - `\.\d{1,8}` Match `.` followed by a digit between 1-8 times. Since the `0` is *implied* here, it's actually the 9th digit for this number (the dot being the tenth).
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

---

For matching the possibility of `+` or `-` at the start of the number, the following may be used.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/V4Etty/2)

```
^(?=[-+\d.]{1,10}$)(?:[-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d{1,8}|[+-]\.\d{1,7})$
```

Comment: Incorrect answer. Sure, it almost answers the question, except that it won't validate an input such as `-12.12345678` or `+12.12345678` (12 characters long), which are both valid Oracle DB literals for `NUMBER(10,8)`. But more importantly, the question is based on a misunderstand of what `NUMBER(10,8)` means, and this answer doesn't correct the misunderstanding, and since the rest of the question is misguided, this answer is equally misguided.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the comment, updated to include possibility of `+` or `-`. But I do agree the OP has misunderstood `NUMBER(10,8)`

Comment: But not the total length of 12 characters. And why only 7 fractional digits if signed?

Comment: @Andreas this is only going off of the OP's misunderstanding. They correctly identified in the question that there is a maximum, but they incorrectly defined that maximum. My answer limits the characters based on the OP's incorrect identification of `NUMBER(10,8)` limitations

Comment: @ctwheels Thanks a lot for explaining the regex in such details! Really appreciate the efforts!

Answer (score -1):

Regex is a chomsky language of typ-3, which can not calculate something. You can only or-combine all possible formats, which results in a long and unmaintainable regex. So the easiest solution is a functional check.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? I did not quite get what you mean by functional check..